# How to use Wake On Demand?

Tags: wifi, wake-on-lan

I want to setup wake-on-demand as described [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3774) so I can remote wake up my computer and ssh into it while I am oversea.

My iMac did not have ethernet connection and I want to wake-up it using Wifi.

Thats what I have:

iMac 27-inch, Mid 2011, Software  OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)

AirPortExpress, version 7.6.4

Raspberry-pi

ISP-provided router (Technicolor TG582n)

My Raspberry-pi is always on so it is fine if I need to ssh into it first to wake up my iMac.

I have follow the instructions provided in the article for iMac. But I don't know how to actually wake up my computer.

From Bonjour Browser, I can see that my AirPortExpress is publishing `_sleep-proxy._udp` so I think it have Bonjour-Sleep-Proxy on.

---

For some reason, I found this line in the log

> mDNSResponder[47]: BeginSleepProcessing: en1    not capable of magic packet wakeup

whereas en1 is my wifi interface. But from System Information

```
en1:
  Card Type:    AirPort Extreme  (0x168C, 0x9A)
  Firmware Version: Atheros 9380: 4.0.74.0-P2P
  MAC Address:  04:54:53:0f:c9:b1
  Locale:   APAC
  Country Code: ES 
  Supported PHY Modes:  802.11 a/b/g/n
  Supported Channels:   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140
  Wake On Wireless: Supported <--- is this lying to me?
  AirDrop:  Supported
  Status:   Connected
```

Answer (score 3):

Both lines are correct. You WiFi card supports Wake-On-Lan (WOL) but the link across it does not.

It's almost impossible to get WOL working across a net of any size as it relies on sending and receiving broadcast UDP packets on port 7 or 9 and broadcast packets are rarely routed.

To get it working you would need to reconfigure your home router and set up a VPN between the router and the device you want to send the WOL packet.

Comment: can you give me more information about how to reconfigure my router? also I should set up VPN between my router and raspberrypi (that can be the device to send packet)?

Comment: I'm sorry but without knowing which router and if it supports a VPN it's impossible for me to be more specific. I suggest you check the manual for your router and on the Raspberry Pi you will need to install OpenVPN.

Answer (score 2):

You need another computer to try to access the sleeping Mac for something.  The easiest way to test this is with a [dedicated WOL client testing program like this](http://www.readpixel.com/wakeonlan/) from another machine on the LAN.  I note that you don't appear to have 2 Macs, but if you google around you will find a way to WOL from whatever build you have on your Pi (likely just a telnet operation using a specific port).  This will prove that the Mac is setup correctly, and you can then proceed to test further by attempting to access some service on the sleeping Mac, like a web server etc, presumable from your Pi, as that seems to be the only other client you describe on your LAN.

Comment: i have another old mac book and tried the WOL client in your link. but after my iMac sleep, the WOL client cannot find it. and Back to My Mac also cannot find it

Answer (score 1):

Your Airport Express should handle the WoL functionality for you. Simply setting up port forwarding to your Mac should work fine.  The sleep proxy will see the packet and wake up the host.  If you already forward port 22 to your Raspberry Pi, then you'll either have to set your port forward to listen from a different port of your choosing, then forward that to port 22 on the Mac.

Be sure your Mac supports Wake on Wireless. Your logs do seem to conflict.  Check system preferences and see if you can enable "Wake for Wi-Fi network access" or "Wake for network access" per the document you referenced.  If it says "Wake for Ethernet network access" then you can't wake over Wi-Fi.

The other answers suggest VPNs or WoL programs, but that really isn't necessary since you have the AirPort Express acting as the sleep proxy for you.

Comment: How do you set up forwarding on an Apple Express?

Comment: @patrix You need to use the AirPort Utility app on Mac or iOS to configure your Airport Express. Look for Advanced Options per the Airport Express [manual](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1613/en_US/airport_express_80211n_2nd_gen_setup_guide.pdf).  Then enter the IPs and ports you want to use on your network.  You probably need to set a DHCP reservation for your Mac to make this work over the long term.